# How do I work with large data with a web application?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask

I recently am wrapping up a personal project that involved using flask, python, and pythonanywhere. I learned a lot and now I have some new ideas for personal projects.

My next project involves changing video files and converting them into other file types for example JPGs. when I drafted up how my system could work I quikly realized that the current platform I am using for web application hosting, meaning pythonanywhere, will be too expensive and perhaps even too slow it since I will be working with large files.

I searched around and found AWS S3 for file storage but I am having trouble finding out how I can operate on that data to do my conversions in python. I definitely don't want to download from S3 operate, on the data in Python anywhere, and then reupload the converted files to a bucket. The project will be available for use on the internet so I am trying to make it as robust and scalable as possible.

I found it hard to even word this question on what to ask as I am not too sure if I am even asking the right questions. I guess I am looking for a way to manipulate large data files, preferably in python, without having to work with the data locally if that makes any sense.

I am open to learning new technologies if that is the case and am looking for some direction on how I might achieve this personal project.

Comment: You can try using AWS lightsail for web and S3 for storage and perform your processing in lightsail vps server. make sure both are in the same region. If dowload of video needs to be faster for users then you can use cloudfront for cdn.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [AWS Elastic Transcoder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/introduction.html)?

> Amazon Elastic Transcoder lets you convert media files that you have stored in Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) into media files in the formats required by consumer playback devices. For example, you can convert large, high-quality digital media files into formats that users can play back on mobile devices, tablets, web browsers, and connected televisions.

Like all things AWS, there are SDKs (e.g. Python SDK) that allow you to programmatically access the service.